# Can I use coroutines in Kotlin when targeting JavaScript?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-js

Is it possible to launch any coroutines when targeting JavaScript?
It doesn't like any of the usual ways like async{}

Example on: https://github.com/thigg/no-kotlinx-in-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Take a look at [`example-frontend-js`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/js/example-frontend-js) — frontend application written in Kotlin/JS that uses coroutines to implement animations in imperative style.

Don't forget to add a dependency on `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core` in your Gradle configs.

Comment: Im on Kotlin 1.3.41. I created a Kotlin JS Project with intellij idea and it says there is no package `import kotlinx.coroutines.*`.
Did I get any config wrong?

Comment: Can't spot differences so far, they seem simply to include the stdlib, nothing else. I'm doing the same as far as I can see. I will build a minimal failing example...

Comment: I created a minimal-not-working-example: https://github.com/thigg/no-kotlinx-in-js maybe you can help me to spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have all the dependencies they have in a sample project. Take a look at parent's build.gradle: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/build.gradle#L130. That `allprojects` configure additional dependencies and plugins.

Comment: Yes, it was the missing import. Thanks. Will you update your answer?

Comment: The link in this answer is now broken. It used to be a helpful example. Where did it go?